# Get iPhone Status Bar Height

Tags: iphone, statusbar

I need to resize some elements in relation to the height of the iPhone's Status Bar. I know that the status bar is usually 20 points high but this isn't the case when it's in tethering mode. It gets doubled to 40. What is the proper way to determine it's height? I've tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]
```

but it gives me 20 x 480 in landscape which is correct but then it gives me 320 x 40 in portrait. Why isn't it giving me the opposite of that (40 x 320)?

Comment: How can statusbar be 40px?

Comment: @Andy when tethering is active the status bar height increases to 40px

Comment: Or when a call comes in

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The statusBarFrame returns the frame in screen coordinates. I believe the correct way to get what this corresponds to in view coordinates is to do the following:

```
- (CGRect)statusBarFrameViewRect:(UIView*)view 
{
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

    CGRect statusBarWindowRect = [view.window convertRect:statusBarFrame fromWindow: nil];

    CGRect statusBarViewRect = [view convertRect:statusBarWindowRect fromView: nil];

    return statusBarViewRect;
}
```

Now in most cases the window uses the same coordinates as the screen, so `[UIWindow convertRect:fromWindow:]` doesn't change anything, but in the case that they might be different this method should do the right thing.

Comment: Calling this method in `-[UIViewController viewWillAppear:]` didn't work. Two issues: 1. The view's window is `nil` then. 2. Even when I preceded the call to `-[UIWindow convertRect:fromWindow:]` with `if (view.window)`, when I popped back to the view controller in landscape mode, the statusBarFrame had width & height switched and the call to `-[UIView convertRect:fromView:]` didn't switch them back correctly.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale Why not call it in `viewDidAppear:` instead?

Comment: Because, I'm adjusting `self.collectionView.contentInset` based on `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame`. If I adjust it after the view appears, then you can see it jump. So, I must adjust it before the view appears.

Answer (score 16):

Did you do it like this:

```
CGRect rect;

rect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
NSLog(@"Statusbar frame: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

Comment: Yes I am. I mentioned that in my initial question.

Comment: You can also use NSStringFromCGRect: `NSLog(@"Statusbar frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));`

Answer (score 7):

This method works for portrait & landscape orientation.

```
-(float) statusBarHeight
{
    CGSize statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size;
    return MIN(statusBarSize.width, statusBarSize.height);
}

// example call
float statusBarHeight = [self statusBarHeight];
```

Comment: could you please provide more details on your solution, thanks!

Comment: This can be used in your ViewController implementation. For example in the 'viewDidLoad' method.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**
The iOS 11 way to work out where to put the top of your view content is UIView's `safeAreaLayoutGuide` See [UIView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide).

**DEPRECATED ANSWER**
If you're targeting iOS 7+, The documentation for UIViewController advises that the viewController's `topLayoutGuide` property gives you the bottom of the status bar, or the bottom of the navigation bar, if it's also visible. That may be of use, and is certainly less hack than many of the previous solutions.

Answer (score 6):

You could test which is the lesser of the two values, that will be the real height.

Comment: Thanks! [I implemented this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598350/242933). It's great!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 2:**

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
```

**Swift 3 or Swift 4:**

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

**Advice:** Don't forget to inject the `UIApplication.shared` do not just use the singleton in your code.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to use the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift version if anyone needs it:

```
var screenStatusBarHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
}
```

This is included as a standard variable in:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Disclaimer: Its my repo