# uninitialized constant Builder::XmlMarkup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to display a comments feed for my application but I keep running into the same error. In my controller I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
format.rss { render :layout => false }
end
```

I then have a index.rss.builder w/ something very similar to http://techgossipz.blogspot.com/2010/03/gnerate-rss-for-your-site-in-rails.html

I am using Rails 3. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the builder gem installed?

Comment: Please accept answers to your older question, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888517/get-iphone-status-bar-height). Thank you.

Comment: @DarkDust I don't accept answers that are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it like this:

```
class RssController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :xml, :html, :rss
    layout false
    after_filter :set_header

    def set_header
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'
    end

    def hu
        @feeds=Feed.order("created_at DESC")
        respond_with(@feeds)
    end

    def en
        @feeds=Feed.order("created_at DESC")
        respond_with(@feeds)
    end

end
```

And you can call /en.rss