# UITableview not visible the last cell when scroll down

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I'm very new to iOS. I have a UITableView that filled with many custom cells, but the bottom cell is is not visible properly when scroll down.my Y value of the UITableView is 44 and Height is 480. Only the half of the last cell is visible when scroll down. How can I fixe this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use -

```
  tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 120, 0); //values
```

> passed are - top, left, bottom, right

Pass bottom offset as per your needs.

Comment: This does not solve the actual problem, the view itself is misaligned not the content.

Comment: This helped me solve a slightly different properly. Where I wanted to tableview to scroll passed its last cell to show a activity indicator. Vote from me!

Comment: This solved my problem as well. Using a custom navigation controller control to present a table view and had the same problem as iDia.

Comment: @rishi, how you calculated 120 ?

Comment: It worked for me, but i don't now why ? . It would be better if someone explains.

Answer (score 5):

it is because you set your tableview's frame wrong, if your view has a navigation bar , usually use this code:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.height -= 44;
```

44 is the height of your navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a status bar visible on the top, then it will occupy 20px which will push down your tableView by the same. To avoid this, make the tableView height 460 instead of 480.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the status bar height value though, something like in this answer should be used instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/7038870/707983

Answer (score 1):

For me this is worked.

I have commented out my code

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //This code will run in the main thread:
    CGRect frame = tableViewObj.frame;
    frame.size.height = tableViewObj.contentSize.height;//commenting this code worked.
    tableViewObj.frame = frame;

});

}
```

That's it. It worked for me. Please make sure you have not changed tableview frame some where while in implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on iOS7 and using a navigation controller toolbar, make sure to set it to translucent:

```
    self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = NO;
```