# iOS: How to fit UILabel text in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my first `iOS` project, so I am learning a lot and have to learn more.

I learnt that in order to fit more items on `UITableViewCell`, I need to subclass it and then use it.  I created `TransactionCell` and in my `ViewController` I use it as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // make last cell visible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928085/uitableview-not-visible-the-last-cell-when-scroll-down
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 120, 0);
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TransactionCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    TransactionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TransactionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }
    TransactionModel *transactionModel = self.transactionsModel.transactions[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    cell.dateAndMonth.text = transactionModel.date;
    cell.name.text = transactionModel.name;
    cell.amount.text = transactionModel.amount;
    cell.categoryImage.image = [self getShortImage:[UIImage imageNamed:transactionModel.category]];
    cell.transactionTypeImage.image = [self getShortImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Debit"]];
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    return cell;
}
```

Also, I set the height of cell as

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}
```

My `xib` looks like
[image]

When I run the project however, I see the following

[image]

Things don't fit up!

**Question**
- How do I make the labels appear completely on `TransactionCell`?
- How do I fit all the elements in a single row without cutting off

I am sure I need to learn something else, but not sure what

Comment: Change the size of the labels in Interface Builder.

Comment: Tried but that did not solve it

Comment: there're too many ways to achieve this, auto layout auto resizing, a very big topic

Comment: I'm not on my mac right now, but if you select the label, and click on the tab with customization options, there should be truncation options. Something like, truncate tail, truncate middle... etc. Play with those settings until it functions like you want.

Answer (score 0):

While your label is selected in the xib, go to the autoshrink section in the attributes inspector and change the option to minimum font scale, I usually set it to around 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Add three separate UILabel inside the cell and set the frame for three different size.

Answer (score -1):

As @Shadowfiend told,you have to work with the auto layout and auto resizing.

Check this link: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

It is nice tutorial on auto resizing the cells and well described too.

Hope it help.