# UITableView dynamic cell heights only correct after some scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` defined in a storyboard using auto layout. The cell has several multiline `UILabels`.

The `UITableView` appears to properly calculate cell heights, but for the first few cells that height isn't properly divided between the labels.
After scrolling a bit, everything works as expected (even the cells that were initially incorrect).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]
    // ...
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestCell"];
    // ...
    // Set label.text for variable length string.
    return cell;
}
```

Is there anything that I might be missing, that is causing auto layout not to be able to do its job the first few times?

I've created a [sample project](https://github.com/blackp/TestTableView/tree/master) which demonstrates this behaviour.

[image: Sample project: Top of table view from sample project on first load.]
[image: Sample project: Same cells after scrolling down and back up.]

Comment: I am also facing this issue,But the below answer is not working for me,Any help on this

Comment: facing the same issue adding layoutIfNeeded for cell doesn't work me as well ? any more suggestions

Comment: Great spot.  This is still a problem in 2019  :/

Comment: I found what helped me in the following link - it's a pretty comprehensive discussion of variable height table view cells: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/826946

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I don't know this is clearly documented or not, but adding `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` before returning cell solves your problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestCell"];
    NSUInteger n1 = firstLabelWordCount[indexPath.row];
    NSUInteger n2 = secondLabelWordCount[indexPath.row];
    [cell setNumberOfWordsForFirstLabel:n1 secondLabel:n2];

    [cell layoutIfNeeded]; // <- added

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I do wonder though, why is it only necessary the first time through? It works just as well if I put the call to `-layoutIfNeeded` in the the cell's `-awakeFromNib`. I'd prefer to only call `layoutIfNeeded` where I know why it's necessary.

Comment: Worked for me! And I would love to know why is it required!

Comment: Did not work if you render size class, that different from any X any

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinov Yup it doesn't work with size class, how do I make it work with size class?

Comment: It works without size class, any solution with size class?

Comment: This helped me (with size class).
Just after you request and set the label's text: `cell.labelText.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.labelText.frame.width`

Comment: I can't believe I've spent so much time to finally find this working answer. :)

Comment: i want to give you this world... :)

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you rintaro.

Comment: If your content gets updated asynchronously later, the height will already have been set. As well as `layoutIfNeeded()` you may need to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`. I put both in a `defer {}` block at the start of my update method.

Answer (score 41):

This worked for me when other similar solutions did not:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This seems like an actual bug since I am very familiar with AutoLayout and how to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension, however I still occasionally come across this issue. I'm glad I finally found something that works as a workaround.

Comment: Better than the accepted answer as it is only called when the cell is being loaded from the xib instead of every cell display. Far less lines of code too.

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.didMoveToSuperview()`

Comment: @cicerocamargo Apple says about `didMoveToSuperview`: "The default implementation of this method does nothing."

Comment: @IvanSmetanin it doesn't matter if the default implementation doesn't do anything, you should still call the super method as it could actually do something in the future.

Comment: (Just btw you should DEFINITELY call super. on that one.  I have never seen a project where the team overall doesn't subclass more than once cells, so, of course you have to be sure to pick them all up.  AND as a separate issue just what TNguyen said.)

Comment: Is that supposed to be in TableView or in the Cell?

Comment: This ONLY helped me working great. The above all did nothing to me(using tableview cell in another tableview cell, Swift 4.0).

Answer (score 22):

Adding `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does not work for cells that are initially scrolled out-of-view.

Nor does prefacing it with `[cell setNeedsLayout]`.

You still have to scroll certain cells out and back into view for them to resize correctly.

This is pretty frustrating since most devs have Dynamic Type, AutoLayout and Self-Sizing Cells working properly — except for this annoying case. This bug impacts all of my "taller" table view controllers.

Comment: Same for me. when I first scroll, cell's size is 44px. if I scroll to make the cell out of sight and come back, it is sized properly. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Thank you @ashy_32bit this solved it for me as well.

Comment: it would seem to be a plain bug, @Scenario right?  horrible stuff.

Comment: Using `[cell layoutSubviews]` instead of layoutIfNeeded might be possible fix. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33515872/1474113

Answer (score 15):

I had same experience in one of my projects.

Why it happens?

Cell designed in Storyboard with some width for some device. For example 400px. For example your label have same width. When it loads from storyboard it have width 400px.

Here is a problem:

`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` called before cell layout it's subviews.

So it calculated height for label and cell with width 400px. But you run on device with screen, for example, 320px. And this automatically calculated height is incorrect. Just because cell's `layoutSubviews` happens only after `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`
Even if you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for your label manually in `layoutSubviews` it not helps.

My solution:

1) Subclass `UITableView` and override `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Set cell width equal to  table width and force cell's layout.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;
    cellFrame.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
    cell.frame = cellFrame;
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

2) Subclass `UITableViewCell`.
Set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` manually for your labels in `layoutSubviews`. Also you need manually layout `contentView`, because it doesn't layout automatically after cell frame change (I don't know why, but it is)

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.yourLongTextLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.yourLongTextLabel.width;
}
```

Comment: When I ran into this issue, I also needed to ensure the tableview's frame was correct, so I called [self.tableview layoutIfNeeded] before the tableview was populated (in viewDidLoad).

Comment: I never stopped to think it had to do with an incorrect width. `cell.frame.size.width = tableview.frame.width` then `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in the `cellForRowAt` function did the trick for me

Answer (score 14):

none of the above solutions worked for me, what worked is this recipe of a magic:
call them in this order:

`tableView.reloadData()

tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()`

my tableView data are populated from a web service, in the call back of the connection I write the above lines.

Comment: For swift 5 this worked even in collection view, god bless you, bro.

Comment: For me, this returned the correct height and layout of the cell, but it had no data in it

Comment: Try setNeedsDisplay() after those lines

Answer (score 10):

I have a similar problem, at the first load, the row height was not calculated but after some scrolling or go to another screen and i come back to this screen rows are calculated. At the first load my items are loaded from the internet and at the second load my items are loaded first from Core Data and reloaded from internet and i noticed that rows height are calculated at the reload from internet. So i noticed that when tableView.reloadData() is called during segue animation (same problem with push and present segue), row height was not calculated. So i hidden the tableview at the view initialization and put an activity loader to prevent an ugly effect to the user and i call tableView.reloadData after 300ms and now the problem is solved. I think it's a UIKit bug  but this workaround make the trick.

I put theses lines (Swift 3.0) in my item load completion handler

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300), execute: {
        self.tableView.isHidden = false
        self.loader.stopAnimating()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

This explain why for some people, put a reloadData in layoutSubviews solve the issue

Comment: This is the only WA that worked for me too. Except I don't use isHidden, but set the table's alpha to 0 when adding the data source, then to 1 after reloading.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried most of the answers to this question and could not get any of them to work. The only functional solution I found was to add the following to my `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

The `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` call is required, otherwise you will see the normal table view animation as the view controller loads.

Comment: working and definitely better than invoking reloadData twice

Comment: Black magic. Doing it in `viewWillAppear` did not work for me, but doing it in `viewDidAppear` did.

Comment: This solution 'did' work for me when implemented in the viewDidAppear. It is by no means optimal for the user experience as the table content jumps around as the correct sizing occurs.

Comment: amazing i have tried alot of examples but fails you are demon

Comment: Same as @martin

Answer (score 5):

In my case the last line of the UILabel was truncated when the cell was displayed for the first time. It happened pretty randomly and the only way to size it correctly was to scroll the cell out of the view and to bring it back.
I tried all the possible solutions displayed so far (layoutIfNeeded..reloadData) but nothing worked for me. The trick was to set **"Autoshrink"** to *Minimuum Font Scale* (0.5 for me). Give it a try

Comment: this worked for me, without applying any of the other solutions listed above.  Great find.

Comment: But this autoshrinks the text... why would one want to have different sizes of text in a table view? Looks terrible.

Answer (score 5):

Add a constraint for all content within a table view custom cell, then estimate table view row height and set row hight to automatic dimension with in a viewdid load   :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

To fix that initial loading issue apply layoutIfNeeded method with in a custom table view cell :

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    // Initialization code
}
}
```

Comment: It's important to set `estimatedRowHeight` to a value > 0 and not to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (which is -1), otherwise the auto row height won't work.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked  but the following combination of the suggestions did.

Had to add the following in viewDidLoad().

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

The above combination of reloadData, setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded worked but not any other. Could be specific to the cells in the project though. And yes, had to invoke reloadData twice to make it work.

Also set the following in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = MyEstimatedHeight
```

In tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: My similar `reloadData/beginUpdates/endUpdates/reloadData` is also working; `reloadData` **must** be called a second time. Don't need to wrap it in `async`.

Comment: I am so glad I scrolled far down enough. This was the only solution for me. 
All I needed was the first part. Not a fan of reloading tableView twice but it certainly works

Answer (score 4):

calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` inside `cellForRowAt` worked for me on ios 10 and ios 11, but not on ios 9.

to get this work on ios 9 also, I call `cell.layoutSubviews()` and it did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` helps in my case.
I added

```
cell.detailLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.frame.width
```

in my code.

Also refer to [Single line text takes two lines in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840137/single-line-text-takes-two-lines-in-uilabel/26840677) and http://openradar.appspot.com/17799811.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the solutions in this page but unchecking use size classes then checking it again solved my problem.

Edit: Unchecking size classes causes a lot of problems on storyboard so I tried another solution. I populated my table view in my view controller's `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Attatching screenshot for your referance]For me none of these approaches worked, but I discovered that the label had an explicit `Preferred Width` set in Interface Builder. Removing that (unchecking "Explicit") and then using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a stack view in the cell was causing the problem. It's a bug apparently. Once I removed it, the problem was solved.

Comment: i tried all others solution, ony your solution worked for thank you for sharing it

Answer (score 2):

## For iOS 12+ only, 2019 onwards...

An ongoing example of Apple's occasional bizarre incompetence, where problems go on for literally years.

It does seem to be the case that

```
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
```

will fix it.  (You're losing some performance of course.)

Such is life with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I have the issue with resizing label so I nee just to do
    chatTextLabel.text = chatMessage.message
    chatTextLabel?.updateConstraints() after setting up the text

// full code

```
func setContent() {
    chatTextLabel.text = chatMessage.message
    chatTextLabel?.updateConstraints()

    let labelTextWidth = (chatTextLabel?.intrinsicContentSize().width) ?? 0
    let labelTextHeight = chatTextLabel?.intrinsicContentSize().height

    guard labelTextWidth < originWidth && labelTextHeight <= singleLineRowheight else {
      trailingConstraint?.constant = trailingConstant
      return
    }
    trailingConstraint?.constant = trailingConstant + (originWidth - labelTextWidth)

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was updating in other cycle. So tableViewCell height was updated after labelText was set. I deleted async block.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:Identifier, for: indexPath) 
     // Check your cycle if update cycle is same or not
     // DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.label.text = nil
     // }
}
```

Comment: I also have an async block but it is needed? Is there no alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you're not setting the label text in 'willdisplaycell' delegate method of table view.
Set the label text in 'cellForRowAtindexPath' delegate method for dynamic height calculation.

You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the initial cells load before we have a valid row height. 
The workaround is to force a table reload when the view appears.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this was far far far far far most better solution that helped me. It didn't corrected the 100% of cell but upto 80% were taking their actual size. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue with the cell height takes place after the initial table view is loaded, and a user action takes place (tapping on a button in a cell that has an effect of changing the cell height). I have been unable to get the cell to change its height unless I do:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I did try

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3. I had to call self.layoutIfNeeded() each time I update the text of the reusable cell.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class CommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let reuseIdentifier = "CommentTableViewCell"

    var comment: Comment! {
        didSet {
            textLbl.attributedText = comment.attributedTextToDisplay()
            self.layoutIfNeeded() //This is a fix to make propper automatic dimentions (height).
        }
    }

    internal var textLbl = UILabel()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if textLbl.superview == nil {
            textLbl.numberOfLines = 0
            textLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            self.contentView.addSubview(textLbl)
            textLbl.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
                make.left.equalTo(contentView.snp.left).inset(10)
                make.right.equalTo(contentView.snp.right).inset(10)
                make.top.equalTo(contentView.snp.top).inset(10)
                make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp.bottom).inset(10)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CommentTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.comment = comment
        return cell
    }
```

---

```
commentsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    commentsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and fixed it by moving my view/label initialization code FROM `tableView(willDisplay cell:)` TO `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: which is *NOT* the recommended way to initialize a cell. `willDisplay` will have better performance than `cellForRowAt`. Use the lastest only to instanciate the right cell.

Comment: 2 years after, I'm reading that old comment I wrote down. This was a bad advice. Even if `willDisplay` have better performance, it iS recommended to initialise your cell UI in `cellForRowAt` when the layout is automatic. Indeed, the layout is computed by UIKit **after** cellForRowAt et **before** willDisplay. 
So if your cell height depends of its content, initialize the label content (or whatever) in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty good workaround for this. Since the heights cannot be calculated before the cell is visible, all you need to do is scroll to the cell before calculating it's size.

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) ?? UITableViewCell()
let size = cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height))
```

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 11+**

table views use estimated heights by default. This means that the contentSize is just as estimated value initially. If you need to use the contentSize, you’ll want to disable estimated heights by setting the 3 estimated height properties to zero: tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0 tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0 tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}

extension YourViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to layoutSabviews

Answer (score 0):

override the prepareForReuse() and set lable to nil in you cell class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.detailLabel.text = nil
        self.titleLabel.text = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way. Double reloadData like that:

```
tableView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: { [weak self] in
   self?.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are not engaging the **main thread** too much

ie :
Don't use `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `TableViewCell` or to set the values... This will engage the main thread and mess up the height of the cell doesn't matter if you use all the above solutions.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


//  call the method dynamiclabelHeightForText
}
```

use the above method which return the height for the row dynamically.
And assign the same dynamic height to the the lable you are using.

```
-(int)dynamiclabelHeightForText:(NSString *)text :(int)width :(UIFont *)font
{

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width,2500);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:font
                                constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                    lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


    return expectedLabelSize.height;


}
```

This code helps you finding the dynamic height for text displaying in the label.

Comment: Actually Ramesh, this shouldn't be needed as long as the tableView.estimatedRowHeight and tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension properties are set.  Also, make sure the custom cell has appropriate constraints on the various widgets and the contentView.