# reloadData() of UITableView with Dynamic cell heights causes jumpy scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I feel like this might be a common issue and was wondering if there was any common solution to it.

Basically, my UITableView has dynamic cell heights for every cell. If I am not at the top of the UITableView and I `tableView.reloadData()`, scrolling up becomes jumpy.

I believe this is due to the fact that because I reloaded data, as I'm scrolling up, the UITableView is recalculating the height for each cell coming into visibility. How do I mitigate that, or how do I only reloadData from a certain IndexPath to the end of the UITableView?

Further, when I do manage to scroll all the way to the top, I can scroll back down and then up, no problem with no jumping. This is most likely because the UITableViewCell heights were already calculated.

Comment: A couple things... (1) Yes you can definitely reload certain rows using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. But (2) what do you mean by "jumpy" and (3) have you set an estimated row height? (Just trying to figure out if there's a better solution that would allow you to update the table dynamically.)

Comment: @LyndseyScott, yes, I have set an estimated row height. By jumpy I mean that as I scroll up, the rows are shifting upwards. I believe this is because I set an estimated row height of 128, and then as I scroll up, all my posts above in the UITableView are smaller, so it shrinks the height, causing my table to jump. I'm thinking of doing reloadRowsAtIndexPaths from row `x` to the last row in my TableView... but because I'm inserting new rows, it won't work, I can't know what the end of my tableview will be before I reloaded the data.

Comment: *how do I only reloadData from a certain IndexPath to the end of the UITableView?*  -- You do that by reading the documentation.

Comment: Note for future answer seekers: It seems as if the issue comes from using `tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. The issue was also mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25999880/2274694

Comment: I was using exact cell heights but was supposedly hit by this, or a very similar problem. Setting the exact size as estimated size (as suggested in several answers, but I could do it directly in my storyboard) fixed that problem - the table view would jump around a bit strangely after deleting some source data and then doing `reloadData()`.

Comment: Can you please re-upload the video? Link appears broken.

Comment: There seems to be a **bug** for when you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension `. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640409/how-to-keep-uitableview-contentoffset-after-calling-reloaddata/31324129#31324129) and other answers to the question. @SrujanSimha

Answer (score 258, accepted):

To prevent jumping you should save heights of cells when they loads and give exact value in `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`:

Swift:

```
var cellHeights = [IndexPath: CGFloat]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Objective C:

```
// declare cellHeightsDictionary
NSMutableDictionary *cellHeightsDictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;

// declare table dynamic row height and create correct constraints in cells
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

// save height
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cellHeightsDictionary setObject:@(cell.frame.size.height) forKey:indexPath];
}

// give exact height value
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *height = [cellHeightsDictionary objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (height) return height.doubleValue;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `cellHeightsDictionary`:  
    
    `cellHeightsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`

Comment: `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` returns a double value may cause a `*** Assertion failure in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]` error. To fix it, `return  floorf(height.floatValue);` instead.

Comment: How should you deal with row insertion/deletion using this solution? TableView jumps, as the dictionary data isn't actual.

Comment: For me this worked with combination of setting estimatedRowHeight, estimatedSectionHeaderHeight, estimatedSectionFooterHeight to 1.

Comment: Works like a charm. Do you have any idea why this happens? I'd suggest that is due to the `UITableView` algorithm used to find the height for cell given an estimated height "considerably far" from the correct/desired/necessary height.

Comment: What if your screen has, let's say, pull-to-refresh and you got new elements inserted at the top? At this moment `[IndexPath: CGFloat]` would be invalidated.

Comment: That actually works. However, the question now is: how come `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` but the regular `heightForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't???

Comment: with dynamic cell height `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` used for calculate cells size on scrolling

Answer (score 112):

Swift 3 version of accepted answer.

```
var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 70.0 
}
```

Comment: After struggling many hours with persistant jumping I figured out that I forgot adding `UITableViewDelegate` to my class. Conforming to that protocol is neccessary because it contains the above shown `willDisplay` function. I hope I can save someone the same struggle.

Comment: This is a great answer - my only suggestion would be to replace your default value in the `estimatedHeightForRowAt:` method with `UITableView.automaticDimension`. This way it will fallback to the (often imprecise but hopefully close) automatically determined value from Apple rather than 70.

Answer (score 42):

The jump is because of a bad estimated height. The more the estimatedRowHeight differs from the actual height the more the table may jump when it is reloaded especially the further down it has been scrolled. This is because the table's estimated size radically differs from its actual size, forcing the table to adjust its content size and offset.
So the estimated height shouldn't be a random value but close to what you think the height is going to be. I have also experienced when i set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
if your cells are same type then

```
func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100//close to your cell height
}
```

if you have variety of cells in different sections then I think the better place is

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     //return different sizes for different cells if you need to
     return 100
}
```

Comment: An old answer, but it is still actual as of 2018. Unlike all other answers, this one suggests setting estimatedRowHeigh once in viewDidLoad, which helps when cells are of same or very similar height. Thanx. BTW, alternatively esimatedRowHeight can be set via Interface Builder in Size Inspector > Table View > Estimate.

Comment: provided a more accurate estimated height helped me. I also had a multi-section grouped table view style, and had to implement `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:)`

Answer (score 29):

***@Igor*** answer is working fine in this case, `Swift-4` code of it.

```
// declaration & initialization  
var cellHeightsDictionary: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [:]
```

in following methods of `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  // print("Cell height: \(cell.frame.size.height)")
  self.cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if let height =  self.cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath] {
    return height
  }
  return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: How to deal with row insertion/deletion using this solution? TableView jumps, as the dictionary data isn't actual.

Answer (score 21):

I have tried all the workarounds above, but nothing worked.

After spending hours and going through all the possible frustrations, figured out a way to fix this. This solution is a life savior! Worked like a charm!

**Swift 4**

```
let lastContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
tableView.setContentOffset(lastContentOffset, animated: false)
```

I added it as an extension, to make the code look cleaner and avoid writing all these lines every time I want to reload.

```
extension UITableView {

    func reloadWithoutAnimation() {
        let lastScrollOffset = contentOffset
        beginUpdates()
        endUpdates()
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
        setContentOffset(lastScrollOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

finally ..

```
tableView.reloadWithoutAnimation()
```

**OR** you could actually add these line in your `UITableViewCell` `awakeFromNib()` method

```
layer.shouldRasterize = true
layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

and do normal `reloadData()`

Comment: How does this do any reloading? You _call_ it `reloadWithoutAnimation` but where's the `reload` part?

Comment: @matt you could call `tableView.reloadData()` first and then `tableView.reloadWithoutAnimation()`, it still works.

Answer (score 13):

I use more ways how to fix it:

For view controller:

```
var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 70.0 
}
```

as the extension for UITableView

```
extension UITableView {
  func reloadSectionWithoutAnimation(section: Int) {
      UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
          let offset = self.contentOffset
          self.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: .none)
          self.contentOffset = offset
      }
  }
}
```

The result is

```
tableView.reloadSectionWithoutAnimation(section: indexPath.section)
```

Comment: Works perfectly but it has only one drawback, you lose the animation when inserting header, footer or row.

Comment: Where would reloadSectionWithouAnimation be called? So for example, users can post an image in my app (like Instagram); I can get the images to resize, but in most cases I have to scroll the table cell off scree for that to happen. I want the cell to be the correct size once the table goes through reloadData.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this today and observed:

1. It's iOS 8 only, indeed.
2. Overridding `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't help.

The fix was actually pretty simple:

Override `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and make sure it returns the correct values.

With this, all weird jittering and jumping around in my UITableViews has stopped.

NOTE: I actually know the size of my cells. There are only two possible values. If your cells are truly variable-sized, then you might want to cache the `cell.bounds.size.height` from `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Fixed it wen overriding the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method with an high value, for example 300f

Answer (score 9):

You can in fact reload only certain rows by using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, ex:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

But, in general, you could also animate table cell height changes like so:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method with an high value, for example 300f

This should fix the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit shorter version:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath] ?? UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a **bug** which I believe was introduced in iOS11.

That is when you do a `reload` the tableView `contentOffSet` gets unexpectedly altered. In fact `contentOffset` should not change after a reload. It tends to happen due to miscalculations of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

You have to save your `contentOffSet` and set it back to your saved value after your reload is finished.

```
func reloadTableOnMain(with offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero){

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] () in

        self?.tableView.reloadData()
        self?.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self?.tableView.contentOffset = offset
    }
}
```

How you use it?

```
someFunctionThatMakesChangesToYourDatasource()
let offset = tableview.contentOffset
reloadTableOnMain(with: offset)
```

This answer was derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324129/5175709)

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me in Swift4:

```
extension UITableView {

    func reloadWithoutAnimation() {
        let lastScrollOffset = contentOffset
        reloadData()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        setContentOffset(lastScrollOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the approach to solve this problem that I found is

```
CATransaction.begin()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
   UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. Here's what I did with **Swift 4 & Xcode 10.1**...

In viewDidLoad(), declare table dynamic row height and create correct constraints in cells...

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Also in viewDidLoad(), register all your tableView cell nibs to tableview like this:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourTableViewCell")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourSecondTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourSecondTableViewCell")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourThirdTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourThirdTableViewCell")
```

In tableView heightForRowAt, return height equal to each cell's height at indexPath.row...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! YourTableViewCell
        return cell.layer.frame.height
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourSecondTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! YourSecondTableViewCell
        return cell.layer.frame.height
    } else {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourThirdTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! YourThirdTableViewCell
        return cell.layer.frame.height
    } 

}
```

Now give an estimated row height for each cell in tableView estimatedHeightForRowAt. Be accurate as you can...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 400 // or whatever YourTableViewCell's height is
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 231 // or whatever YourSecondTableViewCell's height is
    } else {
        return 216 // or whatever YourThirdTableViewCell's height is
    } 

}
```

That should work...

I didn't need to save and set contentOffset when calling tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 different cell heights.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let cellHeight = CGFloat(checkIsCleanResultSection(index: indexPath.row) ? 130 : 160)
        return Helper.makeDeviceSpecificCommonSize(cellHeight)
    }
```

After I added **estimatedHeightForRowAt**, there was no more jumping.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cellHeight = CGFloat(checkIsCleanResultSection(index: indexPath.row) ? 130 : 160)
    return Helper.makeDeviceSpecificCommonSize(cellHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the working solution is

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.performBatchUpdates { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
} completion: { [weak self] _ in
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true) // remove if you don't need to scroll
}
```

I have expandable cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `cell.layoutSubviews()` before returning cell in `func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`. It's known bug in iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0     // if have just tableViewCells <br/>

// use this if you have tableview Header/footer <br/>
tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0 <br/>
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this jumping behavior and I initially was able to mitigate it by setting the exact estimated header height (because I only had 1 possible header view), however the jumps then started to happen *inside* the headers specifically, not affecting the whole table anymore.

Following the answers here, I had the clue that it was related to animations, so I found that the table view was inside a stack view, and sometimes we'd call `stackView.layoutIfNeeded()` inside an animation block. My final solution was to make sure this call doesn't happen unless "really" needed, because layout "if needed" had visual behaviors in that context even when "not needed".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had pagination and reloading data without animation but it did not help the scroll to prevent jumping. I have different size of IPhones, the scroll was not jumpy on iphone8 but it was jumpy on iphone7+

I applied following changes on **viewDidLoad** function:

```
    self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0.0
    self.myTableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
    self.myTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
```

and my problem solved. I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked with "heightForRowAt"

```
extension APICallURLSessionViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    print("Inside heightForRowAt")
    return 130.50
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found if you use `reloadRows` causing a jump problem. Then you should try to use `reloadSections` like this:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section) as IndexSet, with: .none)
}
```