# Insert Custom Section Header Constraint Warning

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I am inserting an extra section to my project with a custom section header xib file, I get this problem where I get all sorts of constraint warning if the current view is at the very bottom of the screen. These warning does not appear if the view is not at the very bottom of the screen when the add button is pressed.

I do not get this problem when I choose to do reloadData instead of inserting a new cell. However, I do not want to re-load the whole table just to get a new cell.

I have uploaded a mini sample project that illustrates my problem. Below is how you could replicate the problem

1. When the app launch you would be 3 sections with 2 rows for each section. With the view at Section 0, if you click the add button, an extra section would be added to the bottom of the table. And that would be section 3. No constraint warnings here
2. Scroll all the way to the bottom until you reached the very bottom of the tableView where section 3 row 0 and section 3 row 1 is displayed. Now click the Add button and you will see all these constraint warnings which I was referring to.

[Github Insert Section Header Sample Project](https://github.com/eddy80310/insertRowTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Auto Layout for positioning views in your view hierarchy, you should avoid setting frame or some fixed dimensions as much as possible. The problem in your code is, you are giving a fixed height for header which is something Auto Layout doesn't like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
  return 260.0
}
```

You should change it to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and inform UITableView about the estimated height:

```
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 260.0
```

so table view will infer the height based on the layout constraints and content in the header.

For more information please read [self-sizing cells and headers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) section in the documentation.

Comment: That does work. So basically, the warning doesn't really mean there is any problem with the layout. It is just Xcode not liking autoLayout with fixed height? Note that I went away with automatic Dimension before because I encountered the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244475/reloaddata-of-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-causes-jumpy-scrolling

Comment: There were no ambiguity in your constraints. You should just have let the table view infer the height of the header based on the constraints instead of setting a fixed height.

Comment: I just realised that your solution created another problem. The stack view for the light blue color completely disappeared on the screen. I would expect there to be a [260-80-80-80 = 20 points height)] for the light blue stack view? Ill ask it in another question though since it is slightly different matter

Comment: Link to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688003/constraint-warning-with-dynamic-section-header