# Maintain current position of UITableView while calling reloadData with variable height custom cells of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView with variable height custom cells and multiple sections which are not fixed, i am trying to implement load more functionality while user reach at first cell.

After fetching data i am arranging records into NSMutableArray which contains multi-dimensional array to store data section vice.

My problem is when i load more data i don't have idea about how many sections and how many rows in each section comes. So i can not add fix values to move my UITableView at particular position using methods like **scrollToRowAtIndexPath** or **scrollRectToVisible**

So every time after getting new record i called **reloadData** to update my **number Of Sections** and **number Of Rows In Each Section**, which also move control to first row of UITableView. I want to be present at current viewing cell not at first cell.

I have also tried answers at [reloadData() of UITableView with Dynamic cell heights causes jumpy scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244475/reloaddata-of-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-causes-jumpy-scrolling)   this question but that are not helping me.

Comment: Your load more is called when you reach the top or bottom of your TableView?

Comment: Top of the TableView.

Comment: You mean you want to stay on the top row **before** fetching the new items, since these new items will sit on top after fetching them?

Comment: I mean i want to stay at same row after apending new rows at top, ex. if i am on row 1 when total records are 20, then if i fetch and append 20 more rows at top, so now my new position in table is 21.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `reloadData` if you want to stay at the same position. Use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` or `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` or `reloadSections` instead.

To refresh modified rows with animation:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourModifiedCell] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

To add rows with animation (number of rows is automatically increased):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourNewCell] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Without animation (untested):

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourNewCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}];
```

Apple documentation: [description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)

Comment: i think you don't understand my question you are missing something, without calling `reloadData` how you can update your tableview `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSection` ?

Comment: @DhavalDobariya I've just changed `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. It does the job correctly and it's documented by Apple in the given link.

Comment: @DhavalDobariya Here code does not reload your `tableView`. It just adding one more section and row in your `tableView` or even you can reload a single particular section/cell instead of reloading complete `tableView`.

Comment: @Cœur  Did you try with dynamic height cells which have no limit about its height. Because i face problem in that case only. And i also try again with `beginUpdates, endUpdates, insertRowsAtIndexPaths and insertSections` methods. But still i have same problem.

Comment: @DhavalDobariya Personally I use storyboards prototype cells, autolayout and Swift. And to trigger automatic row height, I use `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60` in `viewDidLoad`. This code trick with the value `60` seems important, as nothing else was working for me.

Comment: @Cœur  I also used same things, the only difference is that i used .xib files and Objective-C but  that does't make any difference. In my case `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` is the main problem which i can't set accurately because some of my cell has 60 size or some may have 150 or 480. Because it is messaging screen.

Comment: @Cœur i have tried 60 for dynamic value, but still not getting desired output.