# UIRefreshControl jump and flash issues

Tags: objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UITableViewController` with the built-in `UIRefreshControl`. I have two issues with the refresh animation which I want to fix.

1. When I drag and pull the table view, it starts to update data from our server. If the user keeps it dragging, a noticeable offset jump occurs.
2. When the refresh operation ends, the table view hides the refresh control animated. After it finishes hiding it, the control flashes for a a few frames.

[image: Showcase]

The control is set up from UIStoryboard. I set up target and tint color from there. When the action fires my code refreshes the data from our server, which has a callback when the server responds. I stop the refresh control from there:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
});
...
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Is something I do wrong or `UIRefreshControl` is just buggy in iOS 11?

Comment: reload tableView in dispatch_async method

Comment: That makes things even worse. UIRefreshControl completely skips animating and a wrong offset is being set to the table view if I use that way.

Comment: Can you please try to add `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES` to your controller ? `UIRefreshControl` has a lot of issues like this…

Comment: I never hit this kind of behavior when dealing with `UIRefreshControl` & async network requests. So I guess there is bug some where in your code.

Comment: When I move the `-endRefreshing` call after `-reloadData`, the flashing problem disappears. The jumping while dragging is caused by the reloading it seems. How else can I reload?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar issue and this is how I finally fixed it:

1. The 'estimated row height' property needs to be set. Otherwise, `reloadData()` causes a noticeable jump. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244475/reloaddata-of-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-causes-jumpy-scrolling)
2. Calling `endRefreshing()` while the user is still dragging also results in a noticeable jump. To avoid this:

   - When I receive new data from the server, I check if the user is still dragging (`UIScrollView.isDragging`). If this is the case then I don't call `endRefreshing()` immediately, but set a flag instead.
   - I override `scrollViewDidEndDragging` and check the flag there; if set, then I call `endRefreshing()` and clear the flag.

Answer (score 4):

The `UIRefreshControl` is kind of mysterious at this point *(it is affected by many things - do you use large titles, set the `refreshControl` in `viewDidLoad` or elsewhere etc.)*

The best way to get rid of these issues is to stop observing `valueChanged` of the `UIRefreshControl` and do `reloadData` / `endRefreshing` after you're sure there is no dragging (e.g. `scrollViewDidEndDragging`).

Also I was able to reproduce the *activity indicator flickering* of `UIRefreshControl` from your gif this way **(and only for iPhone X-like devices with no navigation bar translucency)**:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

then all I had to do was changing the `edgesForExtendedLayout` and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`.