# UITableView jumps up when I insert rows above the indexPaths that is on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add some rows in my table view. when inserting rows are above the rows which are on the screen, the table view jumps up. I want my table view to stay in the position it is already in when I insert rows above. **Keep in mind:** tableView jump to indexPath that it was showing but after adding rows above, bottom rows indexPaths changes and the new n'th indexPath is something else.

Comment: Are you using batchupdates? Share your code please

Comment: Don't reload, use insert method

Comment: @Bista, he is right, you can add without reloading also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reloadData() of UITableView with Dynamic cell heights causes jumpy scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244475/reloaddata-of-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-causes-jumpy-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not as easy task as one would think. Table view jumps when you add a cell on top because the offset is persisted and cells updated. So in a sense it is not the table view that jumps, cells jump since you added a new one on top which makes sense. What you want to do is for your table view to jump with the added cell.

I hope you have fixed or computed row heights because with automatic dimensions things can complicate quite a bit. It is important to have the same estimated height as actual height for row. In my case I just used:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72.0
}
```

Then for testing purposes I add a new cell on top whenever any of the cells is pressed:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var offset = tableView.contentOffset.y
    cellCount += 1
    tableView.reloadData()
    let paths = [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)]
    paths.forEach { path in
        offset += self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: path)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: offset), animated: false)
    }
}
```

So I save what the current offset of the table view is. Then I modify the data source (My data source is just showing number of cells). Then simply reload the table view.

I grab all the index paths that have been added and I modify the offset by adding the expected height of every added cell.

At the end I apply the new content offset. And it is important to do that in the next run loop which is easies done by dispatching it asynchronously on main queue.

**As for automatic dimensions.**

I would not go there but it should be important to have size cache.

```
private var sizeCache: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [IndexPath: CGFloat]()
```

Then you need to fill the size cache when cell disappears:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    sizeCache[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}
```

And change the estimated height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return sizeCache[indexPath] ?? 50.0
}
```

Also when modifying your offset you need to use estimated height:

```
paths.forEach { path in
    offset += self.tableView(tableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt: path)
}
```

This worked for my case but automatic dimensions are sometimes tricky so good luck with them.