# Jumpy effect when deleting a UITableView row while scrolling manually

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently I'm working on an app that involved presenting data in a `UITableView`. I ran into a problem described below.

**Problem:**

I performed a `delete row` operation on the `tableview` and then called `reloadData()` on the `tableview`. While reloading, if I scroll the `tableView` immediately, there is a jumpy effect observed in the `tableview`.

Here is the code to delete `tableview` row,

```
self.viewModel.data.remove(at: index)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I want to know how to resolve this issue. This is the same functionality we can observe while hiding a Facebook/Instagram post.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244475/reloaddata-of-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-causes-jumpy-scrolling) other question may help you. Basically, you need to save the height for the cells to avoid the jumpy recalculation of the cells height.

Comment: Implementing tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: method helped me to resolve similar problem.

Comment: @tema-orange I’ve already implemented this method and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Also I mentioned that reloadData seems to be unnecessary there..

Comment: @tema-orange Removing `reloadData` from the above code didn't make any difference.

Comment: Do comment the reason for downvoting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `reloadData` reloads the entire table view, which you don't need. To animate deletion of the single row use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.viewModel.data.remove(at: index)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: There is no need for the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Enqueue reloading in main thread and also you don't need to reload whole table unless you have changed a lot of data source, just reload section.

```
self.viewModel.data.remove(at: index)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with:.automatic)
}
```