# Tableview offset changed after reload data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Tableview offset changed after reload data.

> 1 Dynamic row height using auto layout.
>
> 2 Using Navigationbar and tabbar in UIViewController.
>
> 3 Using 2 header in tableivew (My 1st and 2nd header is static all dynamic rows in first section.)

Please check Log

**First time load tableview**

`previousContentHeight -> 291.0 -- previousContentOffset -> 0.0`

`afterReloadDataContentHeight -> 3788.5 -- afterReloadDataContentOffset -> 0.0`

**New data arrived from server and reload data**

`previousContentHeight -> 3788.5 -- previousContentOffset -> 3063.5`

`afterReloadDataContentHeight -> 1719.0 -- afterReloadDataContentOffset -> 580.5`

**Here is reload data function**

```
func prepareReloadData() {
    let previousContentHeight = tblView.contentSize.height
    let previousContentOffset = tblView.contentOffset.y
    print("previousContentHeight -> \(previousContentHeight) -- previousContentOffset -> \(previousContentOffset)")
    tblView.reloadData()
    tblView.layoutIfNeeded()
    print("afterReloadDataContentHeight -> \(self.tblView.contentSize.height) -- afterReloadDataContentOffset -> \(self.tblView.contentOffset.y)")
}
```

Comment: How come after new data, your content size is reducing?

Comment: @kerry Yes notice, But I don't know why content offset is change and also change content size, When I scroll up everything is fine, First time 10 cell is visible, after api call another 10 cell is visible (Total 20 cell after api call).

Answer (score 1):

After lots of time spent and find a solution to this issue

**@Igor** answer is working fine in this case

Here you can [check original answer @Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244475/reloaddata-of-uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-causes-jumpy-scrolling/38729250)

## Swift-5

```
// declaration & initialization  
var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]
```

**UITableViewDelegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? UITableView.automaticDimension // Here you can set specific height like 70 or your cell height instead of automaticDimension, But My suggestion is set automaticDimension
}
```