# iOS8 UITableView won't scroll to footer

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit, ios8

The problem might be related to this post [iOS 8 Auto cell height - Can't scroll to last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686490/ios-8-auto-cell-height-cant-scroll-to-last-row) but here the conditions are different.

I'm not using self-sizing, just a typical UITableView with fixed height cells. that you'd want for a Settings screen. However, I do add a footer and few other subviews below the footer of the UITableView. I do update the contentSize properly to take into account those added subviews.

Everything works fine on iPhone4/5 on iOS7 but the UITableView won't scroll all the way to the bottom on iOS8 although I do see the content if I try the hold+scroll trick. Any idea what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Check `contentInset` property

Comment: the contentInset says bottom 0.0 and top 64.0 (for the nav bar) both when it works (iOS7) and does not work (iOS8). Did you suggest checking something more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Check the frame of the table and see if it goes under the tab bar or toolbar (whatever is at the bottom of the screen).

Comment: there is nothing at the bottom. I ended finding a hack that works by increasing the bottom contentInset so thanks for putting me on that track!