# Scrolling to last row of table view only scrolls half way

Tags: uitableview, swift, scroll

I'm trying to scroll to the last row of a table view after a user has added a comment to a feed:

```
self.loadDataFromParse();

// load the last row
let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections()
let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

if numberOfRows > 0 {
     println(numberOfSections)
     let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
     self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
}
```

But `tableview` only scrolls to about half / 3/4 of the way.
Any input appreciated

Comment: I would get the `UITableViewCell` of the cell at that indexPath. See if it's the last cell.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, how would you go about this?

Comment: `UITableViewCell cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` check the information about this cell. See if it's indeed the last cell in your table. Since it only scrolls 3/4 of the way, it seems this is the 3/4th cell right?

Comment: Thanks, tried that, i get number of rows = 21, but will for the cell: if let cell : TimelineCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)? as? TimelineCell{
                    
                
               println("Last row comments: \(cell.postLabel?.text)");
                } ...... i get nil.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may be helpful of others with same issue.
This issue is a bug, see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686490/ios-8-auto-cell-height-cant-scroll-to-last-row).

I use a footer view for adding comments to a feed so i used its height here and the tableview will scroll to the last row directly above the footer view:

```
self.tableView.reloadData();

            // load the last row


            let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height + self.FOOTERHEIGHT);

            self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;
```

Comment: Calling `self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` before setting the offset will also do the trick, `reloadData` can get expensive.