# UITableView scroll to bottom from current position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

How can I scroll to last row in tableview from current positon, because I have tried this solution:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndex.last!, at: .bottom , animated: false)


let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
            let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)

        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
        }
```

and it doesn't scroll from the current position but from the most top position. Even though **my current position is the last row**

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
func scrollToLastRow() {
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: objects.count - 1, inSection: 0)
  self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Scrolling means, thats from current position. So this code should work.

Otherwise you can specify the frame to scroll using `scrollRectToVisible`

```
tableView.scrollRectToVisible(tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath),animated: true)
```

Comment: I can recommend to check objects.count > 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
yourTableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.init(x: 0, y: yourTableView.contentSize.height - yourTableView.frame.size.height, width: yourTableView.frame.size.width, height: yourTableView.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide some more info that when you want to scroll your tableview to last index,Because this code works perfectly

```
let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: lastRow, section: 0)
customTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Updated

Finally here is working code for me

```
  @IBAction func sendBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.listMessages.append(messageTextView.text)
    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.listMessages.count-1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [lastIndexPath], with: .none)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    messageTextView.text = "";
    }
```

Comment: i've tried your code, but it still same. when i check it in cellforrowat,it keeps scroll entire table eventhough i am in my last row. i checked it by print the row in cellforrowat, it prints from 0 to last row, for each scroll, even though the animation doesn't show it scroll from top.

Comment: can you tell me the position where you are writing  this code

Comment: i add it in sendMessage function. so for each time when user send message it will reload the table and scroll to last row

Comment: Have you added this code after reloading your tableView.If not please do it

Comment: i have do it before                                                                                     //to reload the last row
            let lastIndex = [IndexPath(row: listMessages.count-1, section: 0)];
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: lastIndex, with: .none)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            
            let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.listMessages.count-1, section: 0)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

Comment: Try replace your code by this  to make sure what problem is      @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        if textBox.text?.isEmpty == false {
            self.listMessages.append(textBox.text)
            self.tableView.reloadData
            let lastIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.listMessages.count-1, section: 0)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            textBox.text = "";
        }
    }

Comment: still same T_T , if i add self.tableView.reloadData. it will getting worse which means i have to reload entire row for each send message. and i've changed it to just reload the new cell (new message). but the problem for now is the scrolling. it scroll entire table. and maybe that's how it works? for scrolling i mean

Comment: Yes you are correct that is is needless to reload full table but i was trying to get actual cause why this is happening,It would be better if you can provide me your full class , through GitHub or by some other process if you can

Comment: i found the bug it's caused by this .   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.view.frame.height * 0.3 .      because i want to set the row height is dynamical, when i remove this your code works. but i need the row height to be dynamic

Comment: OK if you want dynamic row height then add these two lines in viewDidLoad     -------yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = yourCellHeightInStoryBoard  and  
yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: about my cell height, how can i get it? it is constant value ? which i set it manually?

Comment: Now i got it you have constraints problem in your layout , so refer to this link  https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686490/ios-8-auto-cell-height-cant-scroll-to-last-row,    it's a bug from apple

Comment: So finally you got the issue :) and I was using iOS 9 and solution is also provided in the link provided by you.Hope you have not missed that

Comment: i have found the solution, check my updated question and btw thanks for giving your time to help me. god bless you

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution and thanks for your appreciation :)

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4

```
func scrollToLastRow() {

    if CommentNameArray.count != 0 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: CommentNameArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.CommentTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }

}
```