# Xcode: Dependency added via Pods is not found, get Undefined Symbol

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

My `Podfile` is

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'REFrostedViewController', '~> 2.4.7'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.4'
pod 'SWTableViewCell', '~> 0.3.6'
```

In my `TransactionViewController`, I do following in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // make last cell visible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928085/uitableview-not-visible-the-last-cell-when-scroll-down
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 120, 0);
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TransactionCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    TransactionCell *transactionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (transactionCell == nil) {
        transactionCell = [[TransactionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    transactionCell.rightUtilityButtons = self.rightButtonActions;
...
}
```

and

```
- (NSArray *)rightButtonActions {
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                                                title:@"More"];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                    [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                                title:@"Delete"];

    return rightUtilityButtons;
}
```

This is from example from [github](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)

when I run my application, `Xcode` fails with following error

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/harith/code/XcodeProjects/pennyapp-ios/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SWTableViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TransactionCell in TransactionCell.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SWTableViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TransactionCell in TransactionCell.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am new to `iOS` programming and not sure how to resolve this.

I do see however, that for my other two dependencies in `Podfile`, I have corresponding `*.a` file in framework, but not for `SWTableViewCell`, what's the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the build logs you'll see warnings about not building libraries because it's missing architectures...

In each of the pod build settings change "Build Active Architectures Only" to NO for all settings (Debug/Dist/Release).

[image]

Comment: My apologies, but where exactly can I find "each of the pod build settings"?

Comment: Go into the Pods project in the side navigator, each pod has a target under that project - look in the build settings for each target (for instance, AFNetworking will have it's own target).  Added a picture I hope makes this more clear.