# Last two rows invisible inside tableView in table view controller because of tabs on bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have table view inside table view controller and I have last two items invisible, I can see only if I can see only when I scroll up but it again scroll down.
I tried to change height of table view like inside viewWillAppear

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.tView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f);
```

or

```
CGFloat bottom =  self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
[self.tView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0)];
self.tView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0);
```

but still last two are invisible by tabs at the bottom of screen (tView is table view).

Comment: Including a screen shot to show how this looks would be a great help - it would let people see what you mean without exercising their imagination too much.

Answer (score 0):

Pls provide in detail. As per my understanding you can try this

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 120, 0); //values passed are - top, left, bottom, right
```

Reference taken from similar question answered at [stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928085/uitableview-not-visible-the-last-cell-when-scroll-down). If it doesnot work, you may need to rearrange frame.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have autolayout constraints set on your table view, that are rendering the result of the changes you think you've made in code not be visibly applied. Is that a possibility?