# How to programmatically get iOS status bar height

Tags: ios, uikit, retina-display

I know that currently the status bar (with the time, battery, and network connection) at the top of the iPhone/iPad is 20 pixels for non-retina screens and 40 pixels for retina screens, but to future proof my app I would like to be able to determine this without hard coding values. Is it possible to figure out the height of the status bar programmatically?

Answer (score 517, accepted):

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height`. But since all sizes are in points, not in pixels, status bar height always equals 20.

**Update.** Seeing this answer being considered helpful, I should elaborate.

Status bar height is, indeed, equals 20.0f points *except* following cases:

- status bar has been hidden with `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` method and its height equals 0.0f points;
- as @Anton here pointed out, during an incoming call outside of Phone application or during sound recording session status bar height equals 40.0f points.

There's also a case of status bar affecting the height of your view. Normally, the view's height equals screen dimension for given orientation minus status bar height. However, if you animate status bar (show or hide it) after the view was shown, status bar will change its frame, but the view *will not*, you'll have to manually resize the view after status bar animation (or during animation since status bar height sets to final value at the start of animation).

**Update 2.** There's also a case of user interface orientation. Status bar does not respect the orientation value, thus status bar height value for *portrait* mode is `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height` (yes, default orientation is always portrait, no matter what your app info.plist says), for *landscape* - `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width`. To determine UI's current orientation when outside of `UIViewController` and `self.interfaceOrientation` is not available, use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`.

**Update for iOS7.** Even though status bar visual style changed, it's still there, its frame still behaves the same. The only interesting find about status bar I got – I share: your `UINavigationBar`'s *tiled* background will also be tiled to status bar, so you can achieve some interesting design effects or just color your status bar. This, too, won't affect status bar height in any way.

[image: Navigation bar tiled background is also tiled to status bar]

Comment: This method yields 1024 (iOS7)

Comment: @MarcMosby, it has nothing to do with iOS7.

Comment: Then what's the actual reason?

Comment: @MarcMosby, see my update. Remembered this issue - thanks to you.

Comment: Yes, as Marc pointed on iOS7 it yeilds 1024 sometimes and 20 sometimes. So this is no longer a fool proof way of determining the height. I doubt this is because of the transparent nature of the status bar on iOS 7. It could be that, it first goes to full screen and then resizes itself. So if you app queries during this transition, you might get the wrong value. May be calling this method with a delay might help on iOS 7.

Comment: @DeepakGM, you should've probably check this before making assumptions. The UI rotation mechanics on iPad did not change for iOS7, this method still works, even in case of initially hidden status bar.

Comment: Doesn't it produce 40 due to retina displays? I think you always have to use view.contentScaleFactor to factor your sizes and points...

Comment: consider improve this answer with MattDiPasquale suggestion

Comment: The orientation issue appears to have been fixed in iOS 8, so no need to check the orientation on devices running iOS 8 and newer.

Comment: @MarcMosby i bet you should have tested on iPad, in landscape mode. This methods always gives the right status bar frame **not depending on the orientation**. If the interface is in landscape mode, we would rather check the statusbar *width*.

Comment: There is a case where status bar height can be zero. If supportedInterfaceOrientations() return UIInterfaceOrientation (incorrect result but no compiler error) instead of UIInterfaceOrientationMask and a viewcontroller is presented and dismissed, status bar height will become zero.

Comment: Also on iPhone X status bar will be higher.

Comment: @pre Yep, iPhone X uses 44.

Comment: I'm always getting zero on iOS9

Comment: For newer iPad like iPad Pro 12.9" 3rd generation and iPad 11", the status bar height is 24 points (48 pixels).

Answer (score 104):

Go with [Martin's suggestion to the question: Get iPhone Status Bar Height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195846/242933).

```
CGFloat AACStatusBarHeight()
{
    CGSize statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size;
    return MIN(statusBarSize.width, statusBarSize.height);
}
```

And in Swift

```
func statusBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    let statusBarSize = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size
    return Swift.min(statusBarSize.width, statusBarSize.height)
}
```

It seems like a hack, but it's actually pretty solid. Anyway, it's the only working solution.

#### Old Answer

The following code, which would go in your custom subclass of `UIViewController`, almost worked to support landscape. But, I noticed a corner case (when rotating from right > unsupported upside-down > left) for which it didn't work (switched height & width).

```
BOOL isPortrait = self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
CGSize statusBarSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size;
CGFloat statusBarHeight = (isPortrait ? statusBarSize.height : statusBarSize.width);
```

Comment: This is not correct. The height of the status bar does not changes when you rotate the device. The width would, but the code above does not show that, nor was that the original question.

Comment: You're right that "the height of the status bar does not changes when you rotate the device." But, as [Ash answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14692362/242933), "in landscape mode, you may find that width and height are swapped." The code above takes that into account.

Comment: This is an interesting issue I have been seeing now as well. It looks like a bug to me on Apple's side, but still needs to be accounted for.

Comment: @lehn0058 It's not a bug, it's how Apple handles the bar internally. It is attached to a window and that window is rotated using a transform. The `statusBarFrame` is returned as the value before the transform.

Comment: It looks better as a property :D `var statusBarHeight: CGFloat`

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
```

Comment: the height returned in different orientations is different. that's strange

Comment: Yes, if rotation is landscape -  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.width  values are switched.

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 3 or Swift 4:**

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Answer (score 10):

While the status bar is usually 20pt tall, it can be twice that amount in some situations:

- when you're in the middle of a phone call (that's a pretty common scenario);
- when the voice recorder, or Skype, or a similar app, is using the microphone in the background;
- when Personal Hotspot is activated;

Just try it, and you'll see for yourself. Hardcoding the height to 20pt will usually work, until it doesn't.

So I second H2CO3's answer:

```
statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
```

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT**
The iOS 11 way to work out where to put the top of your view content is UIView's `safeAreaLayoutGuide` See [UIView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide).

**DEPRECATED ANSWER**
If you're targeting iOS 7+, The documentation for UIViewController advises that the viewController's `topLayoutGuide` property gives you the bottom of the status bar, or the bottom of the navigation bar, if it's also visible. That may be of use, and is certainly less hack than many of the previous solutions.

Answer (score 10):

For iOS 13 you can use:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height
```

Comment: But `keyWindow` was deprecated in iOS 13. This was never the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that the status bar's frame will be in the screen's coordinate space! If you launch in landscape mode, you may find that width and height are swapped. I strongly recommend that you use this version of the code instead if you support landscape orientations:

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [self.window convertRect:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame toView:view];
```

You can then read statusBarFrame's height property directly. 'View' in this instance should be the view in which you wish to make use of the measurements, most likely the application window's root view controller.

Incidentally, not only may the status bar be taller during phone calls, it can also be zero if the status bar has been deliberately hidden.

Comment: This didn't give me the correct height. But, I found different way that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598350/242933

Comment: Yeah this is pretty old code now so is probably no longer a valid answer. Personally I no longer ever have any need to check the height of the status bar, thanks to auto layout.

Answer (score 3):

```
    var statusHeight: CGFloat!
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
         statusHeight = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        statusHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    }
```

Comment: The iOS 13 code here was never correct since `keyWindow` was deprecated in iOS 13.

Answer (score 3):

#### `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` was deprecated in **iOS 13**

> 'statusBarFrame' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.

You can retrieve status bar height in iOS 13 like follows:

```
let statusBarHeight = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height
```

NB! It's optional so make sure you have correct fallback.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Swift way to get screen status bar height:

```
var screenStatusBarHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
}
```

These are included as a standard function in a project of mine: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Answer (score 0):

By default Status Bar height in iOS is `20 pt`.

More info: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: Except when it's not. See above.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way that allow you not directly access the status bar height, but calculate it.

**Navigation Bar height - topLayoutGuide length = status bar height**

Swift:

```
let statusBarHeight = self.topLayoutGuide.length-self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
```

`self.topLayoutGuide.length` is the top area that's covered by the translucent bar, and `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height` is the translucent bar excluding status bar, which is usually 44pt. So by using this method you can easily calculate the status bar height without worring about status bar height change due to phone calls.

Comment: This doesn't work, `self.topLayoutGuide.length` is 0 so the result ends up being -44.

Comment: @nambatee I believe it doesn’t work anymore because I’m iOS 11 Apple uses safeAreaInsets

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

Comment: Could you please provide some context or an explanation on why this answers to the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

## Working as of Xcode 15

If you're using UIKit not sure if the same goes for SwiftUI you have access to this variable `scene` as you see here in SceneDelegate.swift

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    }
    
   ...

}
```

You can then access the status bar height by:

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        // Use this as to your needs.
        let height = scene.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
    }

   ...

}
```

Answer (score -6):

Using following single line code you can get status bar height in any orientation and also if it is visible or not

```
#define STATUS_BAR_HIGHT (
    [UIApplicationsharedApplication].statusBarHidden ? 0 : (
        [UIApplicationsharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height > 100 ?
            [UIApplicationsharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width :
            [UIApplicationsharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
    )
)
```

It just a simple but very useful macro just try this you don't need to write any extra code