# Trying to determine if IOS StatusBar is displayed in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar, uilayoutguide

I am trying to determine if the StatusBar is being displayed when my iDevice is in landscape. I have overridden `viewWillTransitionToSize` so that I can recalculate the view layout, but cannot find any property to show StatusBar status:

```
self.status.statusBarHeight
```

always returns 20, and only the description seems to have anything useful.

```
self.topLayoutGuide.description
```

returns

```
_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fdaa16aec20; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdaa16ac650>>
```

If the device is about to rotate to landscape and

```
_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fdaa16aec20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdaa16ac650>>
```

If the device is about to rotate to portrait.

The fact the the heights returned are incorrect leads me to believe they are not updated properly until after the function.

Comment: Have you tried shifting this logic to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`? This should also be called whilst and after rotation and I figure you want to know the statusbar height for layouting purposes.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991935/how-to-programmatically-get-ios-status-bar-height