# How to animate the status bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, height, statusbar

Does anyone know how to access to the height of the status bar? I am trying to animate the status bar to the top of the screen.

Comment: why would you do that? anyway height (read-only) of status bar is `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991935/how-to-programmatically-get-ios-status-bar-height (there are Swift answers).

Comment: _"trying to animate the status bar to the top of the screen"_ Isn't the status bar already at the top?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically get iOS status bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991935/how-to-programmatically-get-ios-status-bar-height)