# Swift: Trying to get my statusbar back - stopping view from writing below the safespace

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I got my function:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        }
```

And I want to minus the view.frame.height, with the height of the statusbar.
The closest thing I could find was this: [How to programmatically get iOS status bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991935/how-to-programmatically-get-ios-status-bar-height)

I've tried:

> view.frame.height - [UIApplication
>   sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
>
> view.frame.height - 20.0f
>
> view.frame.height - 20

But none of them works as I would hope. I believe it uses pixels, instead of points at the last one, the first two doesn't run at all.

What I'm looking for is:
view.frame.height - statusBarHeight

If it helps, here is my entire viewController.

```
//
//  SceneDelegate.swift
//  BeBetterLogin 0.1
//
//  Created by Samuel Hauptmann van Dam on 15/03/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 BeBetter. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

//        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
//        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            window?.rootViewController = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

And my SceneDelegate.

```
//
//  SceneDelegate.swift
//  BeBetterLogin 0.1
//
//  Created by Samuel Hauptmann van Dam on 15/03/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 BeBetter. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

//        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
//        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
//            window?.rootViewController = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
//            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you specify your controller as UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout or a delegate for your collectionView?

Comment: Here is my entire controller.

https://hastebin.com/temoqebare.m